# How to create same like card in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Current using widget code:

```
Widget buildFavouriteCard(text, image, color) => Card(
clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
),
child: Stack(
alignment: Alignment.center,
children: [
  // InkWell(
  //   onTap: (){},
  // ),
  Ink.image(image: NetworkImage(image),
    child: ClipRRect(
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    height: 250,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
  Text(text,style:utils.textStyleCard(color)),
],
),
);
```

Image is in the link:

[image]

Comment: What is your current problem? How does the current look like?

Comment: Try using Opacity widget for faded background. Place Text on it using Stack Widget

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
  height: 250,
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: NetworkImage('https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1312461204/sample.jpg'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover
    )
  ),
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: Container(
    height: 100,
    width: double.infinity,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.7),
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Diet Churra', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              SizedBox(height: 5,),
              Text('100 gram', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              SizedBox(height: 5,),
              Text('745', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.white,),
              SizedBox(width: 5,),
              Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart, color: Colors.white),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```